# Manipulation and interpretation of xgboost models in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I've been taking a look at the output of `booster.save_model("model.json")`, and I am having trouble understanding the output. It seems as though almost none of the information in `model.json` is actually used for prediction, in fact - suspiciously little. For reference, one such model.json looks like this:

```
j={"learner": {
     "attributes": {},
     "feature_names": [],
     "feature_types": [],
     "gradient_booster": {"model": {"gbtree_model_param": {"num_trees": "1", "size_leaf_vector": "0"}, "tree_info": [0], "trees": [<a single tree>]}, "name": "gbtree"},
     "learner_model_param": {"base_score": "5E-1", "num_class": "0", "num_feature": "5"},
     "objective": {"name": "reg:squarederror", "reg_loss_param": {"scale_pos_weight": "1"}}},
   "version": [1, 4, 2]}
```

where the single tree under `j['learner']['gradient_booster']['model']['trees']` is

```
{
 "base_weights": [-0.4984156, -1.2707391, 0.37819964, -2.128702, -0.5379327, -0.41528815, 1.2452325, -2.9461422, -1.3161767, -1.317807, 0.3579243, -1.2447615, 0.33945537, 0.5203166, 2.272548],
 "categories": [],
 "categories_nodes": [],
 "categories_segments": [],
 "categories_sizes": [],
 "default_left": [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
 "id": 0,
 "left_children": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 "loss_changes": [6771.463, 3341.7627, 3223.7031, 1622.7256, 2004.9153, 1532.3413, 1666.2395, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 "parents": [2147483647, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
 "right_children": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 "split_conditions": [0.073486, -0.11132032, 0.041045856, -0.011401389, 0.104938895, -0.05693599, 0.19832665, -0.8838427, -0.39485303, -0.3953421, 0.1073773, -0.37342846, 0.101836614, 0.15609498, 0.6817644],
 "split_indices": [3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 "split_type": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 "sum_hessian": [10000.0, 5316.0, 4684.0, 2448.0, 2868.0, 2446.0, 2238.0, 1219.0, 1229.0, 1533.0, 1335.0, 1165.0, 1281.0, 1313.0, 925.0],
 "tree_param": {"num_deleted": "0", "num_feature": "5", "num_nodes": "15", "size_leaf_vector": "0"}
}
```

**Question 1**: What is the exact formula for the prediction that a booster makes, as a function of its inputs and these parameters?

I would have expected the prediction to be formed by starting with the base_score and adding the relevant values of `base_weights` during each traversal, but that doesn't seem to be the case, indeed, it appears that the values of the predictions do not depend on `base_weights` (or `loss_changes` or `sum_hessian`)! Here's a brief demonstration (with `xgboost.__version__=1.4.2` and python 3.9.7):

```
import numpy as np, xgboost, json
def new_model():
    return xgboost.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1, max_depth=3, base_score=0.5)
def save_model(model, path):
    model.get_booster().save_model(path)
def load_model(path):
    model = new_model()
    model.load_model(path)
    return model

x = np.random.standard_normal((10000, 5))
y = x.sum(1)

m0 = new_model()
m0.fit(x, y)
pred0 = m0.predict(x)
p0 = '/tmp/m0.json'
save_model(m0, p0)
np.testing.assert_array_equal(pred0, load_model(p0).predict(x))  # test save->load

with open(p0) as f:
    j = json.load(f)
trees = j['learner']['gradient_booster']['model']['trees']
for field in ['base_weights', 'loss_changes', 'sum_hessian']:
    trees[0][field] = np.random.random(len(trees[0][field])).tolist()
p1 = '/tmp/m2.json'
with open(p1, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(j, f)
np.testing.assert_array_equal(pred0, load_model(p1).predict(x))  # this assertion passes! Unexpected!
```

Indeed, the only floating point data that seems to be being used is `split_indices`, but I would have thought that that was nowhere near enough data to describe a regression tree. So if question 1 is too granular to answer here, there's still...

**Question 2**: how is it possible that the model predictions depend only on this one floating point vector, `split_conditions`?

Comment: This question is asking two questions. You may get better or quicker responses splitting this into two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I see it's nine months too late, but here's a rudimentary answer as other people may be interested in this...)

`split_indices` refers to the index (0-based) of the list of features supplied during training. It basically says "At this node (position in the array) use feature N for splitting".

For **split** nodes, `split_conditions` refers to the threshold for splitting -- if `feature < split_condition` go left, if `>=` go right. Plus the treatment of NAs (`default_left` tells you where they go at each split).

In your example the first split would be based on feature #3 at threshold 0.073486.

For **leaf** nodes, the `split_condition` contains the leaf value, i.e. the prediction for observations falling into that leaf. (With possible caveats depending on type of problem, transformations, etc.)
`left_children` and `right_children` have a value of -1 for the leaf nodes.

Hope this helps someone to get started -- there's quite a bit of other details. Some of the info in the `json` is not needed for prediction but allows to calculate e.g. the feature importance metrics and how the tree was constructed.

Finally, for me plotting the tree (`xgboost.to_graphviz(booster=m0)`) helps a lot in interpreting the info in the `json`.
Making an example of a depth=1 (single splitting node, 2 leaf nodes) would be even easier to interpret.

Comment: Thanks, @peter! Looking through it now I see you're quite right, and it makes sense. I guess they were just jamming the minimal data into a single array - not sure I love the naming! :)